Intuition on the induced matrix $1,\infty$-norm
I read in this paper (first paragraph of the "preliminaries" section) that the matrix $1,\infty$ norm  for an $m \times n$ matrix M is equal to $$||M||_{1,\infty} = \max_{j \in [n]} ||M_{:,j}||_{\infty}$$.
However, I also read in this Math SE post that it is actually equal to $$||M||_{1,\infty} = \sum_i \max_j |M_{ij}|=\sum_i ||M_{i,:}||_{\infty}$$
These two results seem incompatible. Which one is correct? And how can we go about proving it? As a secondary question -- is there any textbook that discusses this norm in more detail?
I was able to show that
$$||M||_{1,\infty}= \sup_{||x||_1=1} \max_i |M_{i,:}x| \leq \sup_{||x||_1=1} \max_i ||M_{i,:}||_{\infty}||x||_1=\max_i ||M_{i,:}||_{\infty}$$
For the other direction, I let $x=e_j,$ where j is the index of the column with the maximum absolute value in $M$. Then
$$||M||_{1,\infty} = \sup_{||x||_1=1}||Mx||_{\infty} \geq ||Me_j||_{\infty} = ||M_{:,j}||_{\infty} = \max_i ||M_{i,:}||_{\infty}$$
where the last equality holds because both expressions are simply the largest absolute value of any element in $M$.
So can I conclude that the first link is wrong, and that $||M||_{1,\infty}$ is the maximum absolute value of any element in $M$? If so, I'm surprised I haven't seen this way of expressing the element-wise norm before...
Any help clarifying which is correct would be greatly apprecaited!

The article is right. Notice that the result of the article coincides with yours. The Math SE post defines another norm with that notation, it is not the same you are considering

ok, thank you. Just curious -- have you seen this norm before?  I've never seen the element-wise maximum expressed this way.
